# How to remove %-sign in php string

Tags: php, string, sign

i need to remove % sign from file or image name in directory
which string i use

```
$oldfile = "../wallpapers/temp-uploaded/".$file ;
$newfile = "../wallpapers/temp-uploaded/". trim( str_replace('%', '', $file));

rename("$oldfile","$newfile");
```

But its not work 
reply me which string i use ( trim, str_replace not work
preg_replace  how can i use for remove &%$ etc
 reply back

Answer (score 4):

It could be an issue with other things as your logic seems correct. **Firstly**

```
rename("$oldfile","$newfile");
```

should be:

```
rename($oldfile,$newfile);
```

and:

```
$oldfile = "../wallpapers/temp-uploaded/".$file ;
```

should be:

```
$oldfile = '../wallpapers/temp-uploaded/'.$file ;
```

as there is no need for the extra interpolation. Will speed things up. Source: [The PHP Benchmark](http://www.phpbench.com/) (See "double (") vs. single (') quotes"). And [here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/531433-php-do-you-know-basic-syntax/).

**In regards to the problem,** you have to do some proper debugging:

- Does `echo "[$oldfile][$newfile]";` look as expected
- Make sure the folder and oldfile exists.
- Does `var_dump(file_exists($oldfile),file_exists($newfile))` output `true, false`
- Does `file_get_contents($oldfile);` work?
- Does `file_put_contents($newfile, file_get_contents($oldfile));`
- Make sure you have write permissions for the folder. Typically `chmod 777` will do.
- Before the rename, perform: `if ( file_exists($newfile) ) { unlink($newfile); }` as you will have to delete the newfile if it exists, as you will be moving to it. Alternatively, you could append something to the filename if you do not want to do a replace. You get the idea.

**In regards to the replace question.**

As you have said you would like %xx values removed, it is probably best to decode them first:

```
$file = trim(urldecode($file));
```

You could use a regular expression then:

```
$newfile = '../wallpapers/temp-uploaded/'.preg_replace('/[\\&\\%\\$\\s]+/', '-', $file); // replace &%$ with a -
```

or if you want to be more strict:

```
$newfile = '../wallpapers/temp-uploaded/'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+/', '-', $file); // find everything which is not your standard filename character and replace it with a -
```

The `\\` are there to escape the regex character. Perhaps they are not needed for all the characters I've escaped, but history has proven you're better safe than sorry! ;-)

Comment: i need this if %$# etc in image name then replace it to -or _
how do this?

Comment: @balupton: Why should double quotes be converted to single quotes? Double quotes are just as correct imo.

Comment: @user395167 - I've updated the post to include regular expressions, this is the best way. You have the choice of just what you are after, and a more strict variation.

@Znarkus. I've updated the post to include the reason why, and a source for reference.

Comment: But its not remove % from file or image file name 
image file name is 5035%2C.jpg
 how to remove Percatage sign?

Comment: and need to remove space " " also in file orimage file

Comment: Updated the post, to include urldecode for the % removal. If you would  like them to be removed, rather than replaced, then change the second paramater of preg_replace to '' instead. The PHP manual can tell you this - it's actually A WONDERFUL THING that manual! ;-)

Also updated the first regex to remove spaces as well. The PHP manual also has excellent documentation about regexes so well worth reading. And reading is much easier than asking sometimes ;-)

Comment: its great .. but i want to remove space "  " also in file name or Image name

Comment: I added that request to the above :S. It's the "\\s" in regex means space/tab/newline

Comment: Use @balupton's "more strict" one. It will remove anything that isn't a-zA-Z0-9_-. characters.

Comment: please in $file = trim(urldecode($file)); 
what i do  in this trim string thats remove also Spaces// //in imagename or file name?

Comment: I think you can figure that one out yourself @user395167 ;-) You've got more than enough to material to figure it out. Wouldn't be much of an educator if I just give you all the answers now would I? :-)

Comment: i am a beginner please help me on this removing spaces using $file = trim(urldecode($file));
 please help me

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = trim($file);
$oldfile = "../wallpapers/temp-uploaded/".$file ;
$newfile = "../wallpapers/temp-uploaded/".str_replace('%', '', $file);

rename($oldfile,$newfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace `&%$` in the filename (or any string), I would use preg_replace.

```
$file = 'file%&&$$$name';
echo preg_replace('/[&%$]+/', '-', $file);
```

This will output `file-name`. Note that with this solution, many consecutive blacklisted characters will result in just one `-`. This is a feature ;-)