# Remove '%' from string using preg_replace()

Tags: php, preg-replace

How do I remove **%** from a string using **preg_replace** function?

Here is what I currently have, but the % sign is blocking the twitter share button from processing:

```
<div class="twitter">
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=Just%20Sorc\'d:%20%20'. preg_replace('/((?:http|https|ftp):\/\/(?:[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?[^\s\"\']+)/i','<a href="$1" rel="nofollow" target="blank">$1</a>',$post).'%20--%20via:%20%20http://www.sorcd.com/'.$session_user_id.'%20%20at%20%20" target="_blank" data-count="none"><img src="https://abs.twimg.com/a/1378977615/images/resources/twitter-bird-white-on-blue.png" width="16px" alt="Tweet"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Those are URI encoded spaces.

Comment: So the $post variable pulls content from a mysql database where the value includes a %.  Whenever a variable contains a % sign, the twitter share button does not work.  When the value does not contain a % symbol, the share button works fine.

Comment: Twitter share button posts this URL string and I think where ...only%2012%%20... occurs, this breaks the sharing tool for some reason:  https://twitter.com/share?text=Just%20Sorc'd:%20%20Last%20year,%20only%2012%%20of%20consumers%20bought%20anything%20through%20social%20media.%20--%20via:%20%20http://www.sorcd.com/jeff%20%20at%20%20

Comment: `only%2012%%20` -- you need to URIencode your % char -- this should be `only%2012%25%20` e.g.: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Just+Sorc%27d%3A++Last+year%2C+only+12%25+of+consumers+bought+anything+through+social+media.+--+via%3A++http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sorcd.com%2Fjeff++at++

Comment: Yes! Frank Farmer that is what I need to do!  Can you help me URIencode that within that string, or point me to a resource to learn how?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Your string/URL has URI encoded values like %20 which means they are spaces. Removing % will not solve the problem.

Secondly, this is a possible duplicate of [how-to-remove-sign-in-php-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275730/how-to-remove-sign-in-php-string).

Comment: If the value of $post is "Only 12% of clip coupons."  

And this value is added to the URL string, it creates "www.twitter.com/share?text=Only%2012%%20....

and this breaks the twitter share button.  So, I think I need to somehow make the % sign go away in the value so it doesn't cause problems from the URL string.  But I don't know how.  Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use urldecode() to decode it. '%20' means space

Comment: and this breaks the twitter share button.  So, I think I need to somehow make the % sign go away in the value so it doesn't cause problems from the URL string.  But I don't know how.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Just use the function urlencode.See here:http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php Can it work?

Comment: With the stripslashes function already in there, this doesn't seem to work.  Can you see how I would use urlencode within this function?